# Staggered columns in WrapPanel or Custom Panel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, wpf-controls

I've been trying for a while now and I can't seem to replicate this model without using a grid. I've tried making some simple custom panels and a [wrappanel](/questions/tagged/wrappanel) that makes a new column after n pixels or n number of items which works; however, I'm unable to find a way to stagger each column.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Layout pattern example]

I've made solutions that use a Grid that do stagger the columns however what I need is a panel that uses columns only and is fluid like a [listview](/questions/tagged/listview) where if an item is added, moved, or removed the other items move accordingly (based on index).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want your Panel somewhat like a "living" list the solution needs 2 steps. First implement a panel that is able to arrange the items the way you want. Second add a manager that handles changes of the list. Furtunately all that is quite easy. This manager already exists, its the ItemsControl. Just feed in your ObserableCollection to the ItemsControl.

```
        <ItemsControl Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding YoursItemsObserableCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <local:StaggeredPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Silver" Width="40" Height="40"/>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Margin="3,3,3,0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>   


class StaggeredPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride (Size availableSize)
    {
        foreach (var childo in InternalChildren)
        {
            FrameworkElement child = childo as FrameworkElement;

            if (child != null)
            {
                var childMaxSize = new Size (double.PositiveInfinity, availableSize.Height);
                child.Measure (childMaxSize);
            }
        }

        return availableSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride (Size finalSize)
    {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        bool shift = true;
        double shiftOffset;

        if (InternalChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            FrameworkElement offsetChild = InternalChildren[0] as FrameworkElement;
            shiftOffset = offsetChild.DesiredSize.Height / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < InternalChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                FrameworkElement child = InternalChildren[i] as FrameworkElement;

                if (child != null)
                {
                    double finalY = y;

                    if (shift)
                    {
                        finalY += shiftOffset;
                    }

                    shift = !shift;
                    child.Arrange (new Rect (new Point (x, finalY), child.DesiredSize));

                    x += child.DesiredSize.Width;
                    double nextWidth = 0;

                    if (i + 1 < InternalChildren.Count)
                    {
                        FrameworkElement nextChild = InternalChildren[i + 1] as FrameworkElement;
                        nextWidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;
                    }

                    if (x + nextWidth > finalSize.Width)
                    {
                        shift = true;
                        x = 0;
                        y += child.DesiredSize.Height;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return finalSize; // Returns the final Arranged size
    }
}
```

Comment: This code staggers well and does make sense; however, I've noticed two things about it. 

1. It only looks like my image when the size of the control is at a certain size. So how could I limit each column to only two items?

2. For an even number of items, the last item of the panel instead of going below the second to last item goes into a new column.

Comment: To be honest I don't understand both of your items. For sure you need to adapt the ItemTemplate to fit your needs. No-one can help you here because you didn't mention the type of your items. The code works according your first specification.